# Mapping map to a list of objects which contains a name and a value parameter

Tags: java, dictionary, java-8, mapstruct

I need to map a Map to a list of Object ( has parameters 'name' and 'value').

What I have tried:

- Creating 2 lists of strings, one for the name, the other for value. Then iterating a list of Object and assigning the key list to the 'name' parameter and the value list to the 'value' parameter. This works, but is very messy and looks quite ugly.

My question is, is there any way to put the same logic concisely using Mapstruct, or if not, Java 8?

Comment: Without seeing your code (you should have pasted it into the text and formatted using the "{}" tool) I can only make suggestions. I'm hoping that you're not trying to put "name" and "value" parameters into an instance of Object, but rather created a subclass that does have these fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:  It presumes you have a constructor.

```
class MyObject {
   String name;
   String value;
   public MyObject(String name, String value) {
      this.name = name;
      this.value = value;
   }
}

List<MyObject> objectList = map.entrySet().stream()
   .map(e->new MyObject(e.getKey(),e.getValue())).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the answer. I think I was not very clear with my wording. I have a Map<String, String> and a POJO which has 'name' and 'value parameters ( Both are string). Now, I need to map the map to a list of Object<name, value>.

Comment: You want it the other way around?  A list of objects?

Comment: Edited my comment, published the incomplete one by mistake. But yes, I need a list of objects

Comment: @Zer0, Add you add the code snippet in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you have a map of name and value

```
Map<String, String> params;
```

You can use `map()` to transform your Map entries into newly created objects that will be stored in a list.

```
HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("param1", "value1");
        params.put("param2", "value2");
        List<MyObject> list = params.entrySet().stream().map((entry) -> new MyObject(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue())).collect(Collectors.toList());
        list.forEach((myObject -> System.out.println(myObject)));
```